# Switching to another branch inside pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run a pipeline using Jenkins following the dev -> prod workflow therefore it has two main stages DEV and PROD and each stage i'm different code since in my prod stage i will be using docker.

that's why i will be using the same repository but each stage  has a different branch.
and in the master(prod) branch i have a sub-module using the other branch code.
[image]
So I'm wondering is it possible to use agent to switch between branches or I have to delete the directory and clone the repository using sh?

If my explanation is lacking please tell me clarify it more :)
If anyone has a hint please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible in many ways. Please Take a look at my below example.

```
node {
    stage('clean workspace') {
        deleteDir()
    }
    stage('dev') {
        dir('dev') {
            git url: "https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/test0.git", branch:'dev'   
            sh """
                ls -al
            """
        }
        
        
    }
    stage('prod') {
        dir('prod') {
            git url: "https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/test0.git", branch: 'prod' 
            sh """
                ls -al
            """
        }

    }
    stage('debug') {
        // Here you can see all the folder like dev, prod
        sh 'ls -al $WORKSPACE'
    }
}
```

The above example will checkout my dev branch in `Jenkins Workspace/dev` and prod branch will checkout in `Jenkins Workspace/prod` folder, then you can navigate to that folder and execute/perform the task you want.

Comment: Oh yes that looks very neat i will try it. Thank you :)